# Any known problems with Ruby/Rails in Lion -> Mountain Lion upgrade?

Tags: macos, rails

I am currently running OSX Lion on my Mac and I do a lot of Rails development.

I am wondering if upgrading my system to OSX Mountain Lion is going to really mess up my Rails/Ruby work. I run Ruby off of RVM.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about Ruby or Rails development specifically, but here's some things I had to do after upgrading to 10.8. See also [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/451052/upgrade-to-mountain-lion) and [this blog post](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/27985816073/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-riding-a-mountain-lion).

- I had to install the command line tools package from Xcode's preferences. Xcode no longer includes separate binaries of the LLVM compiler or make or utilities like SetFile by default.
- X11.app is no longer installed by default. Some Homebrew formulas required installing [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/).
- Configuration files in /etc/apache2/ were removed or overwritten. See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/455505/how-do-i-start-apache-in-osx-mountain-lion).
- ImageMagick didn't work until I uninstalled and installed it again with Homebrew.